# UITextField did not round the border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I used this to round top two corners of my UITextFeild

```
 CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.emailFeild.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath;
```

I also have border added to this UITextField as

```
 self.emailFeild.layer.borderColor = [[self colorFromHexString:@"0x3263A3"]CGColor];
self.emailFeild.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.emailFeild.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

but when I run it. It did not round the corners of border and I get this result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask layer doesn't get drawn, just used to compute the mask. Try:

```
-(void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds
                                                   byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    CAShapeLayer*   frameLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    frameLayer.frame = bounds;
    frameLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    frameLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    frameLayer.fillColor = nil;

    [self.layer addSublayer:frameLayer];
}

-(void)roundTopCornersRadius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    [self roundCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight) radius:radius];
}
```